# from the X album or from the album X?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

From the X album or from the album X?

I see both, but I was wondering if there was one form that was more correct than the other. What do you think?

Here's an example of what I mean:

> Drummer Pete Sandoval mentions this song as his favorite from the
> **Altars of Madness** album.

> Drummer Pete Sandoval mentions this song as his favorite from the album **Altars of Madness**.

Comment: Both are grammatically correct. "*... from the album **Altars of Madness***" is more natural.

Comment: You wouldn't say “the *Animal Farm* novel by Orwell” … Generally I think I would be unlikely to say ‘album’ in apposition to the title unless to clarify that I do not mean the title track.

Comment: @AntonSherwood - 'The Animal Farm Novel by George Orwell came out as a piece that received very little attention from many people. ' - [Grades Fixer](https://gradesfixer2019.medium.com/the-hidden-meaning-of-animal-farm-by-george-orwell-e610728fe5ee). Blog on Medium.com. Unintentionally hilarious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example that you presented, both are correct. But that's not always the case. My working theory is that you should only use the word "album" after the title if the discussion has already limited itself somehow to a group of albums.

For example, if someone asked you what some of your favorite albums are, you probably wouldn't answer, "I love the *Revolver* album." Instead, you'd say, "I love the album *Revolver*."

On the other hand, if you were already discussing the Beatles, and someone asked you to name some of your favorite albums of theirs, "I love the *Revolver* album" is perfectly fine. In fact, now that I think about it, it probably sounds slightly more natural to me than "I love the album *Revolver*." But both work.

In your example, Pete Sandoval was the drummer on *Altars of Madness*, and the discussion that you excerpted from has presumably either explicitly or implicitly indicated that Sandoval is discussing his own music.

So, based on this, my impression is that "the X album" is natural only when the discussion has already been narrowed down somehow to a set of albums that includes X.

Comment: You can really only sensibly say 'the Beatles' white album' although I suspect in speech _the album 'The Beatles'_ (its official title) would avoid having to say 'Do you like the The Beatles album?'. If I just said 'Do you like Revolver or Rubber Soul more?' everyone of a pretty wide age range would know exactly what I meant.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't think @MichaelHarvey is disagreeing, but is rather referring to special cases, for example, where the album title starts with "the" (leading to a potential double-the) or ends with "album" (leading to a potential double-album), or is a self-titled album (leading to confusion).